# jinja2 for loop dynamic variable

Tags: loops, variables, dynamic, jinja2

I am trying to use a jinja2 for loop with an array variable whose name is dynamic. The template is

```
london:
  stations:
  - station:
    name: waterloo
  - station:
    name: paddington
paris:
  stations:
  - station:
    name: nation
```

I want to parse this using something like

```
{% for station in country.capital.stations %}
name is {{ station.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

where `country.capital` is a variable that assumes names of capital cities in a loop, and `stations` is an array under that. However, when `country.capital` is `london` (for instance), the above for loop variable tries to resolve `country.capital.stations` instead of `london.stations`.
I've checked, and `country.capital` does resolve to `london`, and if I change the for loop to use `london.stations` it works.

I understand why the above code does not work, and specifying it directly does, but I cannot work out how to make it dynamic, despite trying many combinations of curly, square and curved brackets in various positions.

I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.